# the Difference between Eager Initialization and Lazy Initialization in Singleton Pattern

Tags: java, singleton, eager-loading, lazy-initialization

I find two different ways to implement a singleton pattern, they are Lazy Initialization and Eager Initialization. and the code is:

```
public class EagerSingleton {
    private static final EagerSingleton instance = new EagerSingleton();

    private EagerSingleton() {
    }

    public static EagerSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

… and:

```
public class LazySingleton {
    private static LazySingleton instance;

    private LazySingleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized LazySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LazySingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

It is said that the difference between those two ways is that `EagerSingleton` initializes early during class loading process, and `LazySingleton` initializes late when it is first used. But I can't see the timing difference because both them have private constructors, which means that you can't create an instance by `new` and let it without using (which can see the timing difference). The only way is to use the `getInstance()` method. So when you use this method, the class loading process and `getInstance()` both happen at this time. So it seems that they are not different.

Can someone explain the difference in this example?

Comment: not very different... unless the classes are used somehow else (not *meaningful* with such simple classes, but maybe some more complex ones, for example with some static fields or methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... It is said that the difference between those two ways is that EagerSingleton initializes early during class loading process, and LazySingleton initializes late when it is first used. ..."*

Correct, the *EagerSingleton* class will instantiate the *instance* field during the class initialization.
Whereas, the *LazySingleton* class will wait for the *getInstance* method to be called.

> *"... I can't see the timing difference because both them have private constructors, which means that you can't create an instance by new and let it without using (which can see the timing difference). ..."*

You can utilize the *[class initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)* to evaluate the fields.

Consider the following.

```java
public class EagerSingleton {
    private static final EagerSingleton instance = new EagerSingleton();

    static {
        System.out.println("EagerSingleton instantiated");
    }

    private EagerSingleton() {
    }

    public static EagerSingleton getInstance() {
        System.out.println("EagerSingleton returned instance");
        return instance;
    }
}

public class LazySingleton {
    private static LazySingleton instance;

    static {
        System.out.println("LazySingleton not instantiated");
    }

    private LazySingleton() {
    }

    public static synchronized LazySingleton getInstance() {
        System.out.println("LazySingleton checking instance");
        if (instance == null) {
            System.out.println("LazySingleton instance assigned");
            instance = new LazySingleton();
        }
        System.out.println("LazySingleton returned instance");
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now, create 2 *EagerSingleton* and 2 *LazySingleton* objects.

```java
System.out.println("e1");
EagerSingleton e1 = EagerSingleton.getInstance();
System.out.printf("%nl1%n");
LazySingleton l1 = LazySingleton.getInstance();
System.out.printf("%ne2%n");
EagerSingleton e2 = EagerSingleton.getInstance();
System.out.printf("%nl2%n");
LazySingleton l2 = LazySingleton.getInstance();
```

Output

```
e1
EagerSingleton instantiated
EagerSingleton returned instance

l1
LazySingleton not instantiated
LazySingleton checking instance
LazySingleton instance assigned
LazySingleton returned instance

e2
EagerSingleton returned instance

l2
LazySingleton checking instance
LazySingleton returned instance
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. However, some sources claim that EagerSingleton can lead to unnecessary memory overhead. But when I look at this example, I don't see it happening in practical applications because there is only a small time difference between them.